# Error running "npm start" and "npm install gulp" with Foundations

Tags: gulp, npm-install, zurb-foundation-6, npm-start

I am new to Foundation for Emails and I am just trying to get everything installed, following directions step by step. I have installed Git, and Node.js (the latest version 11.5.0).

I created my project directory (test123) and inside there I am told to run "npm start". I do this and get the following error:

```
Alexandrus-MacBook-Pro-2:test123 alexcrisan$ npm start

> foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 start. /Users/alexcrisan/Documents/sites/test123
> gulp

[09:27:55] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[09:27:55] Failed to load external module babel-register
[09:27:55] Failed to load external module babel-core/register
[09:27:55] Failed to load external module babel/register
[09:27:55] Local gulp not found in ~/Documents/sites/test123
[09:27:55] Try running: npm install gulp
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexcrisan/.npm/_logs/2018-12-26T14_27_55_973Z-debug.log
```

I follow the error code to install gulp, and get this:

```
Alexandrus-MacBook-Pro-2:test123 alexcrisan$ npm install gulp
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git checkout 4.0
npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexcrisan/.npm/_logs/2018-12-26T15_03_01_008Z-debug.log
```

I found some similar answers online but couldn't find a straightforward way to solve this without digging myself into more confusion.

Running Mac OS Mojave (latest).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The git release name of gulp has changed from 4.0 to v4.0.0 which means that git cant find the node module to install it.

if you open your package.json and you should see something like:

```
"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
```

replace it with:

```
"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#v4.0.0",
```

Then delete your node-modules folder and reinstall, it should run fine now.

I know how you feel, this had me confused for a while. To resolve it I looked at the released versions on github (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/releases) and used the v4.0.0 release in place of what was there.